# Added fragment not being showed

Tags: android

I'm working with an `AsyncTask` on a Fragment on android. On its `doInBackground...` it's doing a lot of stuff. But at some point, a boolean flag is set to a specific value, and that flag makes another `Fragment` appear over the first one.

It seems to be appearing, but as the `AsyncTask` is still working, it's not being showed until it ends.

Here's my code:

```
public interface OnDoStuff() {
    public void doSomeStuff();
}
public void setOnDoStuff(OnDoStuff onDoStuff) {
    interfacedoStuff = onDoStuff;
}


// My ASYNC CLASS
whileEnded=false;

@Override
protected MyObjectParams[] doInBackground(MyObjectParams... params) {
    if (whileEnded)
        publishProgress(params);

    if (backgroundTimes > 10)
        whileEnded = true;

    if (whileEnded) publishProgress(params);

    // Do some other stuff
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(MyObjectParams[]... values) {
    myInterface.doSomeStuff();
}
```

This communication works fine. The Fragment is being added. But it's not being shown until the process ends. Here I attach the fragment:

```
public class FragmentShowAnimation extends Fragment {

RelativeLayout layout;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    layout = new RelativeLayout(this.getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCDCDCD"));

    imageView = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animated_background);

    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();

    if (frameAnimation != null) {
        frameAnimation.start();
    }

    layout.addView(imageView);

    return layout;
}

}
```

This fragment is showing an animated layer over the UI.

But it seems like if my fragment is being shown but at the end of the AsyncTask. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I forgot the transition on my MainActivity... Here it is.

```
@Override
public void onDoStuff() {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(messagingLayout).commit();
}
```

**EDIT2:** Attached image to help clarify what I'm doing:

[image]

Comment: Where is the actual fragment transaction code? When does it happen?

Comment: Fragments should not be communicating with fragments, especially not launching them since they're essentially threads in threads. What you want to do is create a method on the activity firing the first fragment, use getActivity().startSecondFragment(yourdata) to let the main thread start the second fragment safely. Fragments should always communicate through their parent activity.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself. Communication is happening using a MainActivity. So the main activity receives the signal to show the second Fragment, and then it adds it.

Answer (score 0):

Your old fragment is still attached until the `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask` isn't finished. I don't see you have it in your `AsyncTas`k but I'll assume you have. After the `AsyncTask`'s `OnPostExecute` method is finished the transition you want is happening.

Try this:

Detach your current fragment (in `OnPostExecute`) and replace it with another by calling the FragmentManager and commiting the new fragment. A way to do this in a certain point of `DoInBackground` is just to return this boolean value and let the `OnPostExecute` finish this process.

Also it's a good pratice to follow the guideliness for `AsyncTask` and implement all relevant methods (4 of them to be exact)

Comment: But I want both fragments coexist in the same timeline. I'm doing the same in other projects, but for this specific one is not working...